# Как создать всплывающее окно в XCode Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, popup

Я создаю справочное приложение. На главном экране расположены ряды иконок, при нажатии на каждую должна всплывать карточка с информацией о предмете. 
Я не смог разобраться, как создать всплывающее окно в XCode с помощью Swift. Всплывающая карточка должна блюрить бекграунд и закрываться свайпом вниз/вверх. В идеале должна быть похожа на просмотрщик фото в Instagram.
P.S. Это мой первый проект и знания Swift оставляют желать лучшего, поэтому просьба объяснить максимально доступно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что вы уже пробовали? найти туториал по блюру пытались? посмотреть как добавить одному вью другой пытались? здесь на СО про обработку свайпов вопросы искали?

Answer (score 1):

Декомпозируйте задачу, сначала разберитесь с блюром, потом с переходами между контроллерами.

Ключевые слова для блюра - UIBlurEffect, UIVisualEffect

- tutorial - [raywanderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial)
- example - [blurApp](https://github.com/TikhonovAlexander/iOS-8-API/tree/master/BlurApp)

Ключевые слова для переходов - UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning

- Articles - [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/view-controller-transitions/)
- WWDC - [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/)
- example - [App](https://github.com/TikhonovAlexander/iOS-8-API/tree/master/CustomAnimatedTransitioning)
- у raywanderlich есть хороший урок на эту тему с котятками

Answer (score 0):

Нужно что-то подобное?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаете вьюконтроллер в сториборде. На главную вьюху ложите UIVisualEffectView, на нее вашу карточку.  Все. Вызываете следующим образом.

```html
- (IBAction)pressMe:(id)sender {
    
    UIStoryboard* mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    rateDialogVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RateDialogVC"];
    [ViewController setPresentationStyleForSelfController:self presentingController:rateDialogVC];
    [self presentViewController:rateDialogVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}

+ (void)setPresentationStyleForSelfController:(UIViewController *)selfController presentingController:(UIViewController *)presentingController
{
    presentingController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
    presentingController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    presentingController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
}
```

Это Objective-C сорри!